How to generate permutations with constraints
I want to generate all possible lists of ["x","y","z",1,2,3] that are ordered in ascending order. "x", "y" and "z" can be any real numbers and so their order can be arbitrary. However, as 1<2<3, 1 must be before 2 and 2 must be before 3. So, for example, the permutation ["x", 1, "y", "z", 2, 3] should be generated, but the permutation ["x", 1, "y", "z", 3, 2] should not be generated.
The simplest solution is
for p in itertools.permutations(["x","y","z",1,2,3]):
    if permutation_satisfies_the_constraint(p):
        yield p

but it is very inefficient, as it would generate many unneeded permutations
(the total number of permutations of 6 elements is 6!=720, but the total number of legal permutations is 6!/3!=120).
What is an efficient way to generate only the permutations that satisfy the constraint on 1,2,3?

@MartinBrown for each permutation of x,y,z, there are about 20 options to insert 1,2,3 (e.g. 1,2,3,x,y,z; 1,2,x,3,y,z; etc.) How do I generate all these options efficiently?

this is a discrete math problem. "with constraints" ==> you should combine the constrained parts before generating the permutations, regardless whether there's a computer involved. the previous comments elaborate on precisely how to combine them.

I find that Stars and Bars is a great tool to visualize this.

One approach is to reformulate the problem in the choice of a permutation for your unconstrained set (["x","y","z"] in your example) and the choice of its positions in the output, while the position of the ordered list ([1,2,3] in your example) are the remaining ones.
For instance, ["z",1,"x","y",2,3] is the permutation ["z","x","y"] and the positions [0,2,3].
Here is the code for a more general answer for your problem with typings and checks where free_list is your ["x","y","z"] and ordered_list is your [1,2,3]:
import itertools
from typing import Generator

def f(free_list: list[str], ordered_list: list[float]) -> Generator[tuple[str|float, ...], None, None]:
    assert len(set(free_list)) == len(free_list), "free_list should have unique elements"
    assert all(x < y for x,y in zip(ordered_list[:-1], ordered_list[1:])), "ordered_list should be strictly increasing"
    out_len: int = len(free_list) + len(ordered_list)
    
    # Choosing a permutation of free_list
    for free_list_permutation in itertools.permutations(range(len(free_list))):
        # Choosing its place in the output
        for free_list_index_in_out in itertools.combinations(range(out_len), len(free_list)):
            out: list[str | float] = []
            
            # Inserting ordered_list and free_list at their place 
            n_free_list_inserted: int = 0
            for i in range(out_len):
                if i in free_list_index_in_out:
                    out.append(free_list[free_list_permutation[n_free_list_inserted]])
                    n_free_list_inserted += 1
                else:
                    out.append(ordered_list[i - n_free_list_inserted])
            
            yield tuple(out)
        

result = list(f(["x", "y", "z"], [1,2,3]))
assert len(result) == 120
assert len(result) == len(set(result))  # Checking uniqueness of results
for element in result:
    assert len(element) == len(set(element))  # Checking uniqueness in one result
    only_ints = [x for x in result if isinstance(x, int)]
    assert sorted(only_ints) == only_ints  # Checking ordering

As said in the comments there are other equivalent reformulations like choosing the permutation and then choosing increasing (with repetitions) indexes where to insert the ordered list elements

Going through all insertion index sets for the numbers and all permutations of the letters:
from itertools import *

for I in combinations(range(6), 3):
    for [*p] in permutations('xyz'):
        *map(p.insert, I, (1, 2, 3)),
        print(p)

Output (abbreviated, Attempt This Online!):
[1, 2, 3, 'x', 'y', 'z']
[1, 2, 3, 'x', 'z', 'y']
[1, 2, 3, 'y', 'x', 'z']
[1, 2, 3, 'y', 'z', 'x']
[1, 2, 3, 'z', 'x', 'y']
[1, 2, 3, 'z', 'y', 'x']
[1, 2, 'x', 3, 'y', 'z']
[1, 2, 'x', 3, 'z', 'y']
...
['z', 'x', 'y', 1, 2, 3]
['z', 'y', 'x', 1, 2, 3]


A benchmark, also including two filtering solutions like in your question to show that we're actually faster than that:
 97.4 ± 0.2 μs  f1
110.1 ± 0.2 μs  Abel_Adary
217.3 ± 0.5 μs  f3
273.6 ± 0.7 μs  f2

Python: 3.12.2 (main, Jun 12 2024, 09:13:57) [GCC 14.1.1 20240522]

Code (Attempt This Online!):
def f1():
    for I in combinations(range(6), 3):
        for [*p] in permutations('xyz'):
            *map(p.insert, I, (1, 2, 3)),
            yield p

def f2():
    for p in permutations(["x","y","z",1,2,3]):
        i = p.index
        if i(1) < i(2) < i(3):
            yield p

def f3():
    for p in permutations(["x","y","z",1,2,3]):
        it = iter(p)
        1 in it
        if 2 in it and 3 in it:
            yield p

def Abel_Adary():
    return f_(["x", "y", "z"], [1,2,3])
from typing import Generator
def f_(free_list: list[str], ordered_list: list[float]) -> Generator[tuple[str|float, ...], None, None]:
    assert len(set(free_list)) == len(free_list), "free_list should have unique elements"
    assert all(x < y for x,y in zip(ordered_list[:-1], ordered_list[1:])), "ordered_list should be strictly increasing"
    out_len: int = len(free_list) + len(ordered_list)
    
    # Choosing a permutation of free_list
    for free_list_permutation in itertools.permutations(range(len(free_list))):
        # Choosing its place in the output
        for free_list_index_in_out in itertools.combinations(range(out_len), len(free_list)):
            out: list[str | float] = []
            
            # Inserting ordered_list and free_list at their place 
            n_free_list_inserted: int = 0
            for i in range(out_len):
                if i in free_list_index_in_out:
                    out.append(free_list[free_list_permutation[n_free_list_inserted]])
                    n_free_list_inserted += 1
                else:
                    out.append(ordered_list[i - n_free_list_inserted])
            
            yield tuple(out)


funcs = [f1, f2, f3, Abel_Adary]

from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
import sys
import random
from collections import deque
from itertools import *
import itertools

expect = None
for f in funcs:
    result = set(map(tuple, f()))
    if expect is None:
        expect = result
    else:
        print(result == expect)

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e6 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):5.1f} ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} μs '
consume = deque(maxlen=0).extend
for _ in range(100):
    random.shuffle(funcs)
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: consume(f()), number=10) / 10
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)

